# Creating a Java Method

Tags: java, methods

I am creating a java program that runs in tie with another file to help create what is called Object oriented programming.

So I have the whole program completed but I am having a hard time understanding how to make it compile and run. I know my problem is within the name of the method. However I dont quiet understand how to know what to call the method. From what I read there is several different types you can call it.

(Also I know the indentation looks messed up, it's right in my actual program)

Here is what I am looking at to help make sense of my question:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.Random;

   public class RockPaperScissors
   {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  class getUserChoice  
  {
     System.out.println("Would you you like to play rock, paper scissors?");
     userChoice = in.nextLine();

     while (!userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock") && !userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper") && !userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors"))
     {
        System.out.println("Invalid entry please try again");
        userChoice = in.nextLine();
     }
     userChoice = userChoice.toUpperCase(); 
     return userChoice;
  } //end of UserChoice

  class getCPUChoice
  {
     computerRandom = r.nextInt(3)+1;

     if (computerRandom == 1) cpuChoice = "Rock"; 
     else if (computerRandom == 2) cpuChoice = "Paper"; 
     else if (computerRandom == 3) cpuChoice = "Scissors"; 
   }

  class pickWinner
  {
     //tie
     if (userChoice.equals(cpuChoice))
     { 
        winner = tie;
     }

     //user has rock
     if (userPlay.equals("rock")) 
     {
        if (cpuChoice.equals("Scissor")) 
        {
           winner = user;
        }

        else if (cpuChoice.equals("Paper"))
        {
           winner = Computer;
        }

        else if (cpuChoice.equals("Rock"))
        {
           winner = tie;
        }
      }

      if (userPlay.equals("Paper")) 
      {
         if (cpuChoice.equals("Scissor")) 
         {
             winner = Computer;
         }

        else if (cpuChoice.equals("Paper")
        {
           winner = tie;
        }

        else if (cpuChoice.equals("Rock")
        {
           winner = user;
        }
      }

      if (userPlay.equals("Scissors")) 
      {
         if (cpuChoice.equals("Scissor")) 
         {
             winner = tie;
         }

        else if (cpuChoice.equals("Paper")
        {
           winner = user;
        }

        else if (cpuChoice.equals("Rock")
        {
           winner = computer;
        }
      }

  }
```

}//end of RockPaperScissors
}

My error I get is:

> RockPaperScissors.java:10: error:  expected
>            System.out.println("Would you you like to play rock, paper scissors?");

Which from what I understand is from not having the class setup up right. Could someone maybe help explain how you know what to name each method correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't put classes in functions.

Comment: So would be more along the line of public static?

Comment: your obviously meant to make the classes methods. and if you didn't then you need ot put the code in the inner classes in methods.

Comment: So it can't be a class, so I'm having a hard time grasping what it should called be to be a method and not a class.

Comment: Actually, apparently you can declare classes in the main method o.o

Comment: It's often said that classes represent nouns, and methods represent verbs; a class is a _thing_, while a method is something _to do_. `getUserChoice` is clearly something that is going to be done, so it should be a method, not a class.  You may want to start with some very basic tutorials to understand these concepts before trying to write your own program.

Comment: @StephenP that is actually a really good allegory. May I use it?

Comment: @ItamarGreen - of course you may! I'm just repeating it myself not claiming any credit for anything.

Comment: @TylerK - now you've added `class pickWinner` which, again, should be a _method_ not a _class_.

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare more than one `public` class in a file
To fix the problem, remove the word `public`.

> However I dont quiet understand how to know what to call the method.

As for this, to call a method, simply use the method name (full example of my answer):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    class something{
        public void someMethod(int argument){
            //this doesn't do anything
        }       
    }
    something s = new something();
    s.someMethod(1);

}
```

Comment: I think the problem is they don't have the basic understanding of class structure.  I would imagine inner / anonymous classes are probably a little over his head for the time being, probably a better approach would be to show how this is done as a single class with methods.

Comment: So if I do something like just class it will bypass that error but still get that I identifier should be expected.

Comment: Tried doing just the class method, and it still doesn't compile. Do I have a bigger issue then that? It returns a ton of errors, errors that didn't exist on previous programs I've done before. I updated my original code in my post to show what I have.

Comment: because class declarations are not methods... they don't return a type.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't valid Java.  You don't create a class to get choices; make it a method.

```
public class RockPaperScissors {

    private static final String [] choices = { "ROCK", "PAPER", "SCISSORS" };
    private Random random;

    public RockPaperScissors() { this(null); }

    public RockPaperScissors(Long seed) {
        this.random = (seed == null) ? new Random() : new Random(seed.longValue()); 
    }

    // An Enum would be better than a number or String
    public String nextChoice() {
        return choices[this.random.nextInt(choices.length)];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes and methods can be defined inside other classes, but neither can be defined inside methods (functions), with the exception of anonymous functions. If this is a standalone program you intended to write, and you intended for `getUserChoice` and `getCPUChoice` to be methods, just remove the `class` keyword before both names and perhaps replace them with `static` if you want them to be static methods of your `RockPaperScissors` class. Methods need to have a return type and in your case, it can be `String`. You would still need to invoke either method in your `main` method.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine this is the sort of structure you are looking for in a "standard" program.  You can declare other classes in other files and import those too.  Your code will generally run in methods within those classes and is all called from the main method which is your entry point.

```
//imports here
public class ClassName {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //main entry point to your program
  }

  private String methodName(String param1) {
    //do some stuff here

    return someValue;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create several classes in a single file. So it should have only one "class" keyword here.

Your methods are not well formatted, you should take a look at the [Java Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) to get started with Java :)

Here is a simple example of class + method :

```
public class MyClass{
   //Attribute

   public int myMethod(int x) {
      return x+1;  
   }
}
```

A method is defined by its visibility (`public`), the returned type (`int`), its name (`myMethod`) and its parameters (`int x`). So here your methods have a "class" returned type, which is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to write some kind of a guess game between a user and a computer...nice but less easier than it sounds.
As many have said you are having trouble because you are declaring classes with a wrong visibility and not exactly at the right place

The names you gave your two classes gives me the feeling they should be methods rather than classes. So It would be simpler two have three methods.

- The main method: that's where you run your game loop
- A getUserChoice(): that's where you ask the user to input its choice (Good that you block the user until he inputs a valid choice)
- The getCPUChoice: That's where you ask the cpu to input his choice

Some one the variables you use will necessarily be shared between more than one method, so declare them at the class level so that they can be accessible wherever necessary. For example:

```
public class RockPaperScissors {

    static String userChoice = "";
    static String cpuChoice = "";
    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Random r = new Random();

    // ... rest of the code here
```

You should instantiate your Random object and declare your computerRandom variable before using them.

Just as a practical illustration I created a game loop (there are often infinite :))  in the main method where I receive the user's input and the computer input and then compare then. Success comes with a congratulation and failure with a try again note. I am not assuming that it is exactly where you were trying to get, but it could be.

Here is my complete illustration code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created by alompo on 07.11.16.
 */

public class RockPaperScissors {

    static String userChoice = "";
    static String cpuChoice = "";
    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Random r = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(true) {
            getUserChoice();
            getCPUChoice();
            if (cpuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase(userChoice)) {
                System.out.println("Good choice, you have a match with the computer");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry mismatch between you and the computer...try again");
            }
        }

    }

    public static void  getUserChoice()
    {
        System.out.println("Would you you like to play rock, paper scissors?");
        userChoice = in.nextLine();

        while (!userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock") && !userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper") && !userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors"))
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid entry please try again");
            userChoice = in.nextLine();
        }
    } //end

    public static void getCPUChoice()
    {
        int computerRandom = r.nextInt(3)+1;

        if (computerRandom == 1) cpuChoice = "Rock";
        else if (computerRandom == 2) cpuChoice = "Paper";
        else if (computerRandom == 3) cpuChoice = "Scissors";
    }
}
```

[image]